# Byte packing like mongdbo objectid

Tags: c#, mongodb, arrays

Mongodb object id is a byte array which lot of information is packed into the byte array as follows:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-TheBSONObjectIdDatatype

ie: given an id `47cc67093475061e3d95369d` it contains datetime, machine, id, and inc information. how do they store all these information into the id?

how are they doing this? how does byte packing is happening?

is there an example to represent this?

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you asking for what the next section at the given link provides?

Comment: I m asking how do they represent all this information with an id as above.

Comment: So not this -- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification?

Comment: that s just to show what data the id contains, i m asking how do they do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time is seconds since Jan-1-1970, which in their example is 1,204,578,057.

For the binary representation, 1204578057 (base 10) is 47cc6709 (base 16).  There's nothing to do.  That's just how it looks to the computer.

To convert that value to a string (for the ObjectId method), just call [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx) with "X":

```
1204578057.ToString("X")
```

The structure itself is fully defined here -- [BSONObjectIDSpecification](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification).

You may also want to research struct layouts here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx

Comment: yeah i was curious about the conversion from `1204578057` to `47cc6709` and how they do it. so it s hex conversion. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if I am not understanding your question, but the format of the ObjectId is given in the link you provided.  In the ID you have given, this means the following:

`47cc67093475061e3d95369d`

Bytes 0, 1, 2 and 3 = timestamp.
`47cc6709` = Timestamp.

Bytes 4, 5 and 6 = Machine Id.
`347506` = Machine Id.

Bytes 7 and 8 = PID
`1e3d` = PID

Bytes 9, 10 and 11 = Increment
`95369d` = Increment

Comment: well i  asking how they are doing that?

Comment: for example: how do they store timestamp into `47cc6709`

Comment: As explained in the docs linked above, the timestamp is stored as a signed integer of secs since 1970.  In this case 1204578057000 secs since the epoch, which is `2008-03-03T21:00:57Z`.

Comment: Also, the question should be asked, why do you need this information?  If you are looking for a way to get Timestamp values out of the ObjectID, have a look at getTimestamp() function in the shell.

Comment: no i m not interested in the timestamp. i want to know how they do it.

Comment: in other words , how they store `1204578057000` into `47cc6709` ?

Comment: @AustinSalonen that s it? they convert timestamp to hex and it does the trick?